# How to make a header row in a table become fixed when scrolling down? (only in table element, not window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

now I've been researching for a while about how to code a table so that the `thead` (or `th`) parts of a table become fixed when you scroll down on the `overflow` scrollbar. I haven't been been very successful since I either find something that is not what I'm imagining or uses a plugin which I don't understand how to work. An example of something that I was looking at is like http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ with their overflow option. I just seem to be getting frustrated and lost, so I figured I'd ask you guys. (I'm a beginning web designer so as dumbed down as possible is good. and im fine with working with `jQuery` and `Javascript` if that matters)

Here's my code so far: http://codepen.io/PorototypeX/pen/iKJAq

Comment: Heres something to get you going http://jsfiddle.net/kZR85/

Answer (score 0):

```
#header_row {
   background: #636363;
   position: absolute;
   width: 1210px;
   z-index: 100;

}
```

The below code will make the tr for thead come out of the srolling area. It's the best I could get with out messing up all the other code.

```
thead tr{
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
}
```

This works, but you'll have set the sizes on the th for it to make sense.

Comment: This does give me the effect I want but however with the position:absolute, it covers up the first row.

Answer (score 0):

see an old post below to help you with floating headers
http://linodh.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/gridview-header-floating-using-jquery.html